# Get Ribbon child Tab/Group "element"

Tags: javascript, ribbon

I need to get `CUI.Tab` object by id/index from current Ribbon by javascript:

```
var ribbon = (SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance()).get_ribbon();

var tab = SomePublicMethodToGetTabFromRibbonByIdOrIndex(); // <--- Subj

var group = new CUI.Group(ribbon, 'Sample.Tab.Group', 'Sample Group', 'Description', 'Sample.Group.Command', null);
var layout = new CUI.Layout(ribbon, 'Sample.Layout', 'The Layout');    
group.addChild(layout);
tab.addChild(group);    

group.selectLayout('The Layout');
SelectRibbonTab('Standard tab', true);
```

I didn't found any public method for it, though. Am I missing something, or should I override the whole tab now?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
var tab = ribbon.getChild(your_tab_id);
```